# Date-value missmatch after manual Input

Tags: excel, vba

Via Inputbox I want to define the date used in a cell.

```
Sub Refresh()

Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = InputBox("Give me a starting date")
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Y:\ 3300.xls"
Range("A1").Value = myValue
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

The weird thing is, that sometimes the given date is correct, some times reversed (checked by reopening the given file). I tried the following dates :

30/01/17 is correct
14/05/17 is correct
04/02/17 is reversed to 02/04/17
08/09/17 is reversed to 09/08/17
10/05/17 is reversed to 05/10/17
05/10/17 is reversed to 10/05/17

The cell format is according the above (dd/mm/yy) and the behaviour stays even if I change it and adapt the input accordingly

Comment: Most likely your system formatting in mm/dd/yy and February 4th 2017 changes to 02/04/2017. 30/01/17 remains as it is because it stays in the general format, since we only have 12 months. It is not an actual date. You can confirm by enclosing the cells containing the dates in `=value()`. The first two will give a `#VALUE` error while the rest will be converted to their respective underlying number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel doesn't recognise your entry as a date.  It's all just text entered to an inputbox and Excel tries to format it when you add it to the sheet.  By adding `CDATE` it converts the entered value to a real date - I'm sure someone will correct me here if I'm wrong, but it appears to convert it using your local settings.

Another potential problem I see is that you're just looking at the `ActiveWorkbook` which may not be the one just opened.  The code below adds the workbook to a variable so you can be sure you're always looking at the correct book and the correct sheet in that book.

```
Sub Refresh()

    Dim myValue As Date
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    myValue = InputBox("Give me a starting date")
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open("Y:\ 3300.xls")
    wrkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = CDate(myValue)
    wrkBk.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```